# Group, order, and count, by day-of-week in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table with a `timeslot` column (datetime type). I would like to issue a query and have it return with data like so:

```
Sunday | 24
Monday | 32
Tuesday | 12
Wednesday | 93
Thursday | 22
Friday | 66
Saturday | 25
```

Basically, ordered by day-of-week (Sunday -> Monday) in the first column, and the `count(*)` of the rows in the second column.

So far, I have a query like so:

```
order_query = "CASE
    WHEN DAYNAME(CONVERT_TZ(timeslot,'UTC','America/Toronto')) = 'Sunday' THEN 1
    WHEN DAYNAME(CONVERT_TZ(timeslot,'UTC','America/Toronto')) = 'Monday' THEN 2
    WHEN DAYNAME(CONVERT_TZ(timeslot,'UTC','America/Toronto')) = 'Tuesday' THEN 3
    WHEN DAYNAME(CONVERT_TZ(timeslot,'UTC','America/Toronto')) = 'Wednesday' THEN 4
    WHEN DAYNAME(CONVERT_TZ(timeslot,'UTC','America/Toronto')) = 'Thursday' THEN 5
    WHEN DAYNAME(CONVERT_TZ(timeslot,'UTC','America/Toronto')) = 'Friday' THEN 6
    WHEN DAYNAME(CONVERT_TZ(timeslot,'UTC','America/Toronto')) = 'Saturday' THEN 7
END"

week = ProfessionalAvailability.where.not(appointment_id: nil).group('DAYNAME(CONVERT_TZ(timeslot,"UTC","America/Toronto"))').order(order_query).count
```

Which works for my case. However, as you can see, `order_query` is a rather long string, and I wanted to know if there was a simple ActiveRecord way for me to do this.

My DB is in MySQL.

Many kind thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Check out [group_date](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) as an example to see how this is possible if you want to build the SQL queries yourself, or simply do it for you.